# Redirect output of vim command to external program

Tags: vimscript

I would like to filter the output of vim commands with fzf. The idea is for example, if I use vim unimpaired plugin and I don't exactly remember which map was to navigate to the next git conflict but I do remember that it started with "[", to be able to do something like:

```
:map [ | fzf
```

And then I can search for "conflict" or "git" to explore the different mappings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
com -nargs=+ FF call fzf#run({'source' : split(execute(<q-args>), "\n"), 'sink':'"'})
```

Examples:

```
FF map [
FF set termcap
FF buffers
FF oldfiles
```

[:h :quote](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#%3Aquote) is used as sink, it's ignored.

**update**

Filter blank lines, add `-bang` to support reverse order, add `sink` to copy into default register.

```
command! -nargs=+ -bang -complete=command FF call fzf#run({
            \ 'source' : filter(split(execute(<q-args>), "\n"), {i,v->!empty(v)}),
            \ 'sink': function('s:ff_sink'),
            \ 'options' : <bang>0 ? '--tac' : ''})

" copy into @@, ignore leading index
function! s:ff_sink(item)
  let text = substitute(a:item, '\v^\>?\s*\d+\:?\s*', '', '')
  let @@ = empty(text) ? a:item : text
endfunction
```

Answer (score 2):

Redirect the output of the command to a new window, then use `:BLines`. This is mainly useful for editing the output.

```
function! Exec(cmd)
redir @a
exec printf('silent %s',a:cmd)
redir END
tabnew
norm "ap
endfunction
```

This function executes the command and printes the output onto a new tab. I use it from time to time.

For example try :

```
call Exec('nmap')
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't fully understand what you mean, could you fully elaborate with an example? How do I redirect the output of the command to a new window?

Comment: `call Exec(' your command')` would do it if you change `tabnew` to `new`

Answer (score 1):

If you're only interested in working with fzf plugin you probably should do as @dedowsdi suggests. I'm going to talk about the general case, as stands in the question title.

1. First of all, let's not forget that Vim has a builtin function for filtering command output which can come in handy on many occasions. Its usage (`:h :filter`) is quite straightforward:

   ```
   :filter /conflict/ map [
   ```
2. We can create a command of our own mixing `system()` and `execute()`:

   ```
   function! Pipe(...)
       let l:bar = index(a:000, "\<bar>")
       if l:bar <= 0 || l:bar >= a:0 - 1
           return ''
       endif
       let l:result = execute(join(a:000[: l:bar - 1]))
       return system(join(a:000[l:bar + 1 :]), l:result)
   endfunction

   command! -nargs=+ -complete=command Pipe echo Pipe(<f-args>)
   ```

Now you can do `:Pipe map [ | grep "conflict"`, or whatever else.

3. The typical redirection pattern in Vim requires a (temporary) buffer usage. That is, dumping output into a buffer, filtering it, etc.

To redirect commands' output into a buffer you can use the following mapping:

```
nnoremap <silent><leader>x :-1put=trim(execute(input(\":\")))<CR>
```

Now press `<leader>x` and type any command you like.

When the result gets into buffer you can either redirect it to an external terminal window (note that visual mode / Ex ranges are supported too):

```
:w !grep "conflict"
```

or simply apply a filter in-place:

```
:%!grep "conflict"
```

Comment: This is very general, I love it. Thank you

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with `:Pipe map [ | fzf`I'll guess I'll have with the plugin option as I would like to dynamically filter

Comment: @Blasco Definitely, it does work: it opens another terminal window to run fzf, and echoes the result back in Vim after it's ready. If you're seeking for a tighter integration of fzf and Vim you're suggested to explore/reuse code written by the fzf's author (as it's in two other answers). I'm not going to rewrite the whole plugin myself.